# Creating and seeding a torrent in golang

Tags: go, torrent

I want to use the golang library https://github.com/anacrolix/torrent to create to torrent and get a magnet and seed the torrent. Below you can find the code I wrote. Yet, if I use the magnet the code generates I can not download anything not even the metainfo.
Am I missing something here?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
    "github.com/anacrolix/torrent"
    "github.com/anacrolix/torrent/bencode"
    "github.com/anacrolix/torrent/metainfo"
)

var builtinAnnounceList = [][]string{
    {"http://p4p.arenabg.com:1337/announce"},
    {"udp://tracker.opentrackr.org:1337/announce"},
    {"udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:6969/announce"},
}

func main() {

    tmpComment:="Cool torrent description"
    tmpCreatedBy:="coolboys"
    tmpInfoName:="CoolInfoName"
    mi := metainfo.MetaInfo{
        AnnounceList: builtinAnnounceList,
    }

    mi.SetDefaults()
    
        mi.Comment = tmpComment

        mi.CreatedBy = tmpCreatedBy
    //}
    //mi.UrlList = args.Url//???????????
    info := metainfo.Info{
        PieceLength: 256 * 1024,
    }
    err := info.BuildFromFilePath("./TorrentFiles")//args.Root)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

        info.Name =tmpInfoName
    mi.InfoBytes, err = bencode.Marshal(info)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    tmpMagnet:=mi.Magnet(nil,nil)
    log.Println("****",tmpMagnet)

    //
    cfg := torrent.NewDefaultClientConfig()
    cfg.Seed = true
    mainclient, ncerr := torrent.NewClient(cfg)
    if ncerr != nil {
        log.Println("new torrent client:", ncerr)
        return
    }
    defer mainclient.Close()    
    t, _ := mainclient.AddMagnet(tmpMagnet.String())

    for {   
        log.Println("******", t.Seeding())
        time.Sleep(8 * time.Second)

    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What was the expected result/output?  What output are you actually getting?

Comment: I excepted to have  a  magnet I can use to download the torrent files somewhere else. Yet the code just waits doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to take a closer look at [this example](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/anacrolix/torrent#example-package).  Among other things, I don't see any invocation of `t.DownloadAll()` to do the actual download or `mainclient.WaitAll()` to tell you when the downloads are complete.

Comment: if I include t.DownloadAll() and/or mainclient.WaitAll() the code panics  with runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Comment: I think that here AddMagnet is not appropriate as it was designed to load an existing torrent

Comment: This is not a package I have ever used myself, but I would recommend you look through what other adopters from the list [here](https://github.com/anacrolix/torrent#downstream-projects) are doing.  For example, https://github.com/YouROK/TorrServer looks like it might be a similar use case?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback provided. I contact the original author of the library and I did correct m code more details about the discussion can be found here: https://github.com/anacrolix/torrent/issues/804

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the code I wrote and the correct code can be found here:
[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/kendrickjung/0e00c7732b2d882d9f7aa8d699088f05)

In the original code I should not have used addmagnet as it assumes that I don't have the info available, which is why it would fail to seed.

Comment: Provide context for links
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible.